# Do "lamb" and "ram" share a common etymology?

Tags: etymology, nouns

A couple of times, I've noticed Japanese people mistakenly use "ram" instead of "lamb". For [example](http://en.visit-hokkaido.jp/food/bbq.html)

> You broil lamb [correct] or mutton with vegetables. There are roughly two ways
>   to have Genghis Khan; either you broil the marinated meat or dip the
>   broiled meat in sauce. The difference between mutton and **ram** is in
>   stages of growth. The sheep for mutton is two or more years after its
>   birth, and that for **ram** is less than 12 months after its birth. [emphasis added]

This made me wonder: is the similarity between the two words, apart from the l/r difference, describing the same animal a coincidence?

Etymology online says that [ram](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ram&allowed_in_frame=0) and [lamb](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lamb&searchmode=none) are West Germanic and Germanic respectively,  while Wiktionary traces [lamb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lamb#Etymology) back to Proto-Indo-European but merely [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ram) that ram comes from Old English.

Is it known whether the two are related? Failing that, is a change from an "l" to "r", or vice versa, unlikely enough to rule out this possibility?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently not, at least not in relatively recent times. *Ram* is ultimately from Latin ‘aries’, while *lamb* seems to have an entirely Germanic etymology.

**EDIT:**

Here's the OED's etymology for *ram*:

> Etymology:  Cognate with Middle Dutch *ram* male sheep, (after classical
>   Latin *ariēs*) battering ram (Dutch *ram*), Middle Low German *ram* male
>   sheep, Old High German *ram* male sheep (Middle High German *ram*, German
>   *Ramm*-, now rare and chiefly in compounds), perhaps < the same Germanic
>   base as Old Norse *rammr* strong (perhaps on account either of the
>   animal's physical strength or of its strong smell), further etymology
>   uncertain, perhaps < the same Indo-European base as Old Russian
>   *ramjan*″, *raměn*″ strong. Compare post-classical Latin *ramma ram,*
>   piledriver (14th cent. in British sources).
>
> In sense 3 after classical Latin *ariēs* siege engine designed to break
>   down walls, battering ram, spec. use of *ariēs* male sheep (see Aries
>   n.); compare also Middle Low German *ramme* battering ram, Old High
>   German *ramma* battering ram (Middle High German *ramme* , German *Ramme* ,
>   now also in sense ‘hammer in a pile-driving machine’ (compare sense
>   4a)).

Comment: Which <s>sauce</s> source did you get this from?

Comment: The online OED. Some may prefer other sauces for their lamb.

Comment: I'd like to see details of that Latin derivation--not that I don't trust the OED, but it seems phonetically unlikely. And [*etymonline*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ram&searchmode=none), which usually consults (if not downright cribs from) OED, gives  an entirely different account.

Comment: @StoneyB: Answer amended accordingly. Perhaps not entirely conclusive, but good enough to claim  a Latin derivation for the present purpose. Remember that the accusative singular of _aries_ is _ariem_.

Comment: I take it that 'sense 3' is battering-ram; in light of the cognates cited I would call that a [**calque**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) or loan translation rather than a derivation. I leave to Germanists the relevance of declined forms.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why Japanese speakers have trouble with *ram* and *lamb* is because Japanese does not have two non-nasal resonant phonemes (/r/ and /l/) as English does, but only one, which sometimes sounds like [l] and sometimes like [r] to English ears, but always sounds like the same phoneme to Japanese speakers.

Consequently, any word that requires a distinction between English /r/ and /l/ will cause trouble for Japanese speakers. Ask any Japanese what they think of the English word *squirrel* /skwərl/ if you are really interested. It's one syllable in English, but Japanese speakers hear 5, of which the last two are identical (Japanese syllables consist of one consonant followed by a vowel; there are no clusters like /skw/).

Comment: Studying Japanese makes me forget that not everyone would know about "r" and "l" not being distinct in Japanese.

Comment: The OED gives /ˈskwɪrəl/, and I think that’s how I pronounce it.

Comment: I believe Japanese airlines hope their passengers will have a good fright.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I’ve heard Stephen Fry imitate an American saying *squirrel* to contrast how he normally says it in RP, and it is definitely quite different: he has two syllables (as, I suspect, do you), while in North America it has just one, rhyming with *girl* and *pearl* (amongst others).  It honestly never occurred to me that it might have an “alternate” two-syllable pronunciation before I heard Mr Fry do so.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, that must account for it.

Comment: /skwɝl/ would make an excellent US English shibboleth.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, both the Japanese words seem to translate back into English as '*lamb*'.

[image: English-Japanese]

[image: Japanese-English]

The error in the quoted passage could be due to automatic translation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so much as provide another example of it.

Comment: My inference was that the error was caused in translation. cf. "The error in the quoted passage could be due to automatic translation."